# How to setup JSX in netbeans?

Tags: reactjs, netbeans-8, jsx

I am trying to use JSX with Netbeans 8.2

From what I understood, the JSX file should work like the SASS functionality in netbeans, ie, when i save the JSX file, it automatically compiles into a .js file which is referenced in my code.

Is this actually the case in netbeans and if so, how do i set it up? If not, please do guide me towards tutorials on how to use JSX in Netbeans.

Grateful to anyone who can help

Comment: Nope, you are supposed to use babel or some other transpiler for that and I don't know of any special integration plugin for it. Syntax highlighting and basic autocomplete support does work since 8.1 though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.